# Loop/Copy/Paste

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy-paste

I added a piece of code below to already existing code, the good news is that it works! The bad news is it has realllllly slowed down the macro. Was wondering if there is something I can do differently to make this run faster.

I'm trying to loop through all the worksheets in the workbook, search for "X" in the range (LastRow x LastColumn), if there is an "X" in a cell I want to paste values "X".

thanks!
Josh

```
For Each y In SubAssyArray
 Sheets(y).Activate
 Set ws = ActiveSheet
 Set StartCell = Cells(12, 10) 'Cell J12
 LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
 LastColumn = ws.Cells(StartCell.Row, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 3 '-3 columns to not count need date or ECD info
    For i = 10 To LastColumn 'Set from which column number you want the loop to start from
        For j = 12 To LastRow
            If Cells(j, i).Value = "X" Then
                Cells(j, i).Copy
                Cells(j, i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                Else
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
Next y
```

Comment: first, do not activate the sheet.  Just do `Set ws = WorkSheets(y)`  Second do not use the clipboard: `Cells(j, i).Value = Cells(j, i).Value` does it without the copy paste.

Comment: Did you set [Screenupdating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.screenupdating) ?

Comment: thank you @ScottCraner! Didn't realize I didn't need to activate y from my array. Your solution worked perfectly. I also noticed my main issue was I forgot to set y = nothing so it just kept looping and looping and looping...lol oops!